# So you think you know the priority of operators in c++?

Tags: c++, operators

I just ran into a piece of code that not only compiles, but gives the expected result (where x is an integer value):

```
int y = (int)(0.5 * x * x + + + 0.6 * x + 1.2);
```

It took me a while to figure out what happens and I must say it was an interesting operator problem. Without compiling the program, what are the results of the following operations and why?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int z = a + + + b;
int z1 = a + - + b;
int z2 = a + - - b;
int z3 = a - - + b;
int z4 = a - - - b;
int z5 = a +- b;
```

I still have one question, though: does the standard give such results or is it compiler specific?

---

Explanation:
Because the + and - operators have spaces between them, the "+ + +" sequence is not compiled as "++ +", but as unary operators on the right member. So

```
int y = (int)(0.5 * x * x + + + 0.6 * x + 1.2);
```

actually gives:

```
int y = (int)(0.5 * x * x + 0.6 * x + 1.2);
```

which was the expected result.

So,

```
z  = a + + + b = a + + (+b) = a + (+b) = a + b = 3;
z1 = a + - + b = a + - (+b) = a + (-b) = a - b = -1;
z2 = a + - - b = a + - (-b) = a + (+b) = a + b = 3;
z3 = a - - + b = a - - (+b) = a - (-b) = a + b = 3;
z4 = a - - - b = a - - (-b) = a - (+b) = a - b = -1;
z5 = a +- b = a + (-b) = a - b = -1;
```

Comment: Gives the "expected value"? Does it print an informational to the screen saying "That compiles, but I've no idea why you'd want it to"? That's what I'd expect.

Comment: Not really interested in artificial coding quizzes, thanks.

Comment: if the result was really expected, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Find who wrote that, kick them, and tell them not to do it again.  Why do people write this kinda stuff?

Comment: And x * x + + (because + + + is parsed as ++ +)which is same as x*x++ invokes UB :P.

Comment: @Prasoon there is no "+++" in the code - these are mostly unary + and - operations.

Comment: I am tempted to vote for closing as 'Not a real question', but I guess that a proper question in there is 'Why are those the results of the operations?'

Comment: No UB here, note spaces in between. This is a lot simpler than you expect based on your experience with similar quizzes you may have seen and solved before.

Comment: No, actually that's the catch, it's not +++, but + + + (with spaces bettween) and that si why the operators are considered unary operators. And unary operators have higher priority than binary + or -

Comment: @Neil: You are right ;-) .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z = 3
z1 = -1
z2 = 3
z4 = 3
z5 = -1

Without compiling, i'd say it's a simple math operator combining
I've learned it with this phrase (translated from Brazilian portuguese):

> Different signs = subtract
>   Equal signs = add

So

```
int z = a + + + b; // '+' + '+' = '+' , the resulting '+' + '+' = + again.
int z1 = a + - + b; // '+' + '-' = '-' , the resulting '-' + '+' = - again.
int z2 = a + - - b; // '+' + '-' = '-' , the resulting '-' + '-' = +.
int z3 = a - - + b; // '-' + '-' = '+' , the resulting '+' + '+' = + again.
int z4 = a - - - b; // '-' + '-' = '+' , the resulting '+' + '-' = -.
int z5 = a +- b; //simple "different signals = subtract" :)
```

Comment: compiled it now, and it's really this. :)

Answer (score 20):

Answering the question as formulated in the title:

## So you think you know the priority of operators in c++?

No, I do not think so, and even more, I have no intention to learn it. Whenever unsure when reading, I will check documentation, whenever unsure when writing, I will use parentheses. I need my memory to remember more important things.

Comment: In the Real World, all quizzes are open-book.  (Or, as one of my teachers used to say, "open-neighbor.")

Comment: More than once, while reading, I thought I know, but in fact I didn't and missed the bug someone else made. So I prefer to know...

Comment: Not to mention that, if I learn the priority, I'm going to rely on it sometime.  Either I'm going to get it wrong (my memory isn't as good as I remember it being), or I'm going to confuse somebody else.  I can always look it up.

Answer (score 4):

[[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)] Unary +/- bind tighter than addition/subtraction +/-, and associate right. Thus...

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int z = a + + + b; // equivalent to a + (+(+b))
int z1 = a + - + b; // equivalent to a + (-(+b))
int z2 = a + - - b; // equivalent to a + (-(-b)) = a + b
int z3 = a - - + b; // equivalent to a - (-(+b)) = a + b
int z4 = a - - - b; // equivalent to a - (-(-b)) = a - b
int z5 = a +- b; // equivalent to a + (-b) = a - b
```

Answer (score 2):

To sort of answer you question, the answers are not compiler specific. It is neither implementation defined nor undefined behavior.